# Same key, different values: nested dicts of dicts

Tags: grep

Borrowing an MWE from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591811/nested-dicts-in-python-keys-and-values), I have a set of nested dicts of dicts:

```
{
  "type": "A"
    "a": "aaa",
    "payload": {"another":{"dict":"value", "login":"user1"}},
    "actor": {"dict":"value", "login":"user2"}
}
{
  "type": "B"
    "a": "aaa",
    "payload": {"another":{"dict":"value", "login":"user3"}},
    "actor": {"dict":"value", "login":"user4"}
  }
}
{
  "type": "A"
    "a": "aaa",
    "b": "bbb",
    "payload": {"another":{"dict":"value", "login":"user5"}},
    "actor": {"dict":"value", "login":"user6"}
  }
}
{
  "type": "A"
    "a": "aaa",
    "b": "bbb",
    "payload": {"login":"user5"},
    "actor": {"login":"user6"}
  }
}
```

For dictionaries that have `"type":"A"`, I want to get the username from the `payload` dict and the username from `actor` dict. The same username can appear multiple times. I would like to store a txt file with a list of `actor` (ID1) and a list of `payload` (ID2) like this:

```
ID1    ID2
user2  user1
user6  user5
user6  user5
```

Right now, I have a start:

```
zgrep "A" | zgrep -o 'login":"[^"]*"' | zgrep -o 'payload":"[^"]*" > usernames_list.txt
```

But of course this won't work, because I need to find login within the payload dict and login within the actor dict for each dict of type A.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have the `payload` and `actor` dictionaries for all entries of `type` A.

1. Parse out the user name from the `payload` entries and redirect them
   to a file named payload.txt
2. Parse out the user name from `actor` entries and redirect them to a
   different file named actor.txt
3. Use `paste` command to join the entries and output them the way you want it

Comment: But how do I isolate which `login` is which? That is, there is a `login` in `payload` - how do I get just THAT login and not the login from `actor`?